# Converting a website that runs using a Docker container from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: docker, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, containers

I have a Linux (ubuntu 18.04) VM that has Docker on it and inside the containers of Docker my applications are running using Nginx. I want to install a SSL certificate on these applications so the websites will have https. I searched for a way to apply the certificate on them even when they're inside Docker containers but I couldn't find a way to do that I found only ways that work on a VM and not on a container.

I tried to ssh to a container and to apply the certificate as if it was a VM using [this](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx) guide but it resulted in networking errors.

EDIT: I realized let's encrypt work for public websites and decided to use OpenSSL to be able to do it privately.
The Ubuntu VM is in a private network in an Azure Cloud environment and so the websites are private.

Comment: Hey Zoibator--welcome to StackOverflow! Generally, SO tries to keep all questions unique. I think that questions similar to yours have already been asked, so you should search around some. For example, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810165/run-docker-service-on-https or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846649/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-with-docker-container-based-on-the-node-js-image . If this isn't actually a duplicate, please edit the post to make it clear why this problem is novel!

Comment: I have reviewed these questions and the first question refers to a Windows image and I'm using linux Ubuntu and the second question refers to public website while mine are private websites, but thank you for that!